# SQL Server 2019: InitPersistentVersionStore failed after installing CU2

Tags: sql-server, installation, error-log, sql-server-2019

I have installed SQL Server 2019 CU 2 over a vanilla install of SQL Server 2019 RTM.

Now I am puzzled by the following messages in the error log at startup:

> RecoveryUnit::InitPersistentVersionStore failed with db [1] name
>   [master]
>   RecoveryUnit::InitPersistentVersionStore failed with db [4] name
>   [msdb]

AFAIK the PersistentVersionStore links to the new feature [Accelerated Database Recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/accelerated-database-recovery-concepts?view=sql-server-ver15) however I have not configured it.

Here's a screenshot from the error log:
[image: screenshot from errorlog]

The error occurs again after a service restart.

Is it automatically enabled with CU2 for system databases? Is there anything I can do about this error in order to resolve it?

I already did a web search with the error message but most surprisingly didn't find anything regarding to it.

Quick update (March 16th):

- Opened a Ticket with Microsoft Support (no answer yet)
- Installed SQL Server 2019 CU 3: Error persists at service restarts just as with SP 2

Comment: I'm not seeing that - are you seeing it every time you start up, or was it only a one-time thing? Can you include the error messages before/after that so we can see roughly when in startup it's happening? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @BrentOzar: Thanks for stopping by....I feel honored. I added the screenshot. Already tried a restart but the error persists

Comment: I do see a new message since the upgrade `Db Id [5]. Persistent store table, rowset id 72057594042908672, rowset id in recovery unit 72057594042908672, write session partition number 1. Inserts will be optimized` - `is_accelerated_database_recovery_on` is off for that database so not sure why I see that. I don't see anything related to `master` though

Comment: @MartinSmith I see that too. I have one database using ADR though.

Comment: This is still happening on SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU22) (KB5027702) with no ADR in sight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I got an official answer from Microsoft Support which I am glad to share here:

> Hello Martin,   Hope you are fine.   Thanks for call yesterday. As
>   validated from Product Group:
>
> This is only a info message and not a bug. All system databases that
>   come from SQL17 to SQL19 will not have persisted version store
>   initialized because of the way we did upgrade step in SQL17. But this
>   should not affect customer’s databases.”   But we probably will not
>   fix the message on next releases as it’s harmful – that’s why was not
>   fixed until now.   The question we have discussed, as this is
>   something that harmful but should not be there, so you will not be
>   charged for this case.   I will close the case and mark it as product
>   issue.

It's a bit contradictory on whether the message will be fixed or not....last statement on the phone was that in a problematic case it typically arises as a followup error due to database recovery problems. In my case that is not true and it's totally unproblematic...I even don't use ADR.

A big recommendation for everyone upgrading from SQL 2017:
Do not perform an in-place-upgrade but rather do a fresh install of SQL 2019 to avoid seeing this error message.