# InitPersistentVersionStore failed after installing CU2 on multiple instances

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I saw this on another post, but I can't comment on it. So I am opening a new one, but I am having a similar issue that Martin Guth [had posted](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/260228/sql-server-2019-initpersistentversionstore-failed-after-installing-cu2).

It is odd, but I updated about 9 of my instances to CU2 for 2019 a few weeks ago. Every day, around 3 am, I am getting messages in the error log for this:

> ```
> 03/09/2020 03:00:01: RecoveryUnit::InitPersistentVersionStore failed with db [5] name [master]
> 03/09/2020 03:00:01: RecoveryUnit::InitPersistentVersionStore failed with db [5] name [master]
> 03/09/2020 03:00:04: RecoveryUnit::InitPersistentVersionStore failed with db [5] name [msdb]
> 03/09/2020 03:00:04: RecoveryUnit::InitPersistentVersionStore failed with db [5] name [msdb]
> ```

I get this for one of my instances, and for the other one, I get this:

> ```
> 03/09/2020 03:00:03: RecoveryUnit::InitPersistentVersionStore failed with db [14] name [master]
> 03/09/2020 03:00:03: RecoveryUnit::InitPersistentVersionStore failed with db [14] name [master]
> ```

I agree with Martin, I checked ADR, and it is not enabled in my environment at all at the moment. So I am not sure where this is coming from or why, but it started after I updated to CU2. I did do it via dbatools in powershell, along with three others, but the others are not exhibiting this behavior.

If anyone has any suggestions, I am open to them. If I do not hear anything, I will open an issue with Microsoft as well.

Comment: I would open up a ticket with Microsoft if you have a support contract. According to Microsoft there have been [issues with 2019 CU2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4536075/cumulative-update-2-for-sql-server-2019). Your issue might be the third in the CU2.

Comment: Yeah i opened one up with them this morning. Curious to what the solution will be. although we are probably a few weeks only away from cu3 which will more than likely resolve all the cu2 issues, but we will see where that goes.

Comment: @MatthewLee [CU3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4538853/cumulative-update-3-for-sql-server-2019) was released today.

Comment: @taryn I seen you posted this on Twitter. Appreciate that. I have updated all my 2019 instances to cu3. And I heard back from Microsoft and they said that they are hiding this message with the release of cu4 and that it’s nothing to be worried about. They were able to duplicate the message on their system too.

Comment: I  have installed CU3 but the messages are still present at each startup

Comment: The messages will not go away until cu4 is what the Microsoft tech told me. They said at the time it was too late to include them in cu3 since it had already shipped. So after we install cu4 when it comes out, those messages should subside.

Comment: @MatthewLee Got the same response...however it is not yet determined when the message will be fixed. Probably not in CU4...as MS Support told me...Have a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/260228/sql-server-2019-initpersistentversionstore-failed-after-installing-cu2/264225#264225

Comment: This annoyance is still occuring on SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU22) (KB5027702)